# Crontab to Restart Informix

Tags: cron, informix

I have an informix engine in my office and i have to query a bunch of complicated sql. The query can run faster everytime I restart my informix.

Q : Is there any harm if I restart the informix everyday using crontab?

thank you

Comment: A daily or weekly restart using crontab is something we do since a long time, no problems so far, so i don't see any reason why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I don't see why restart the engine and the relation how the query run faster whe restart it... theoretically should be inverse because there is no data cached at buffer pool when start the engine. The unique reason I see for that is if there others users working concurrently and someone is consuming all resources of the database or your database memory consumption at OS goes to swap. Anyway... as first test, I suggest put the instance in quiescent and back it online before run your SQL, this to is to check if the problem isn't concurrent user.

Comment: Also recommend check the OS to see if there some CPU and memory/swap consumption by Informix process before that or any restart and try understand why you need do that. This kind of behave looks like misconfiguration. I work with Informix instance where we keep them uptime +100 days without need to restart. Some instances transcend one year online without restart without major problems...